# AngularJS - "length" method not counting space character at the end of a string

Tags: angularjs

I was trying to count the length of a string(**$scope.count = $scope.str.lenght**). But, when there is a space at the end of the string its not being counted until there is a character after the space.
Example:

```
"Hello " = 5,  
"Hello u" = 7
```

Any idea why is it designed in this way?
How can I count the space at the end of the string?

Comment: post your code. what you have tried

Comment: In console, `"Hello   ".length` get true output! insert some code please.

Comment: @Saeed.At Pure javascript works fine, it's Angular that seems to trim the ngModel value.

Comment: Try `ng-trim="false"`

Answer (score 2):

By default Angular will trim the trailing spaces on ngModel. To override this behaviour add:

```
ng-trim="false"
```

[more info](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D)

```js
(function() {
 'use strict';
  
  angular.module('myApp', []);
  
  angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', MyController);
  
  MyController.$inject = [];
  function MyController() {
    var main = this;
    main.someText = 'abcde';

  }
  
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController as main">
    <input type="text" ng-model="main.someText" ng-trim="false">
    {{main.someText.length}}
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your having the problem with angular ngModel not for the Javascript. Because it is working correct in javascript

```js
console.log("hello ".length)
console.log("hello u".length)
```

> In Angularjs I would suggest @giovani answer